# Neither chat nor meta is mentioned in the tour (/about)

Tags: feature-request, chat, meta

The main "[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/about)" link says:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

While we're happy that SE is not a forum, new users can be put off by this fact. And it's not even a fact: We do have chat! It's in the chat room, but the entire page makes no mention of this brilliant sideshow.

**Please mention the awesome chat in the tour.**

Some sites [suffer](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-do-you-make-involvement-in-meta-more-enticing-less-intimidating) from poor meta participation. It was pointed out that meta is not mentioned in the tour either - and with the new top bar, its link is not even visible without clicking into a menu.

**Please mention the meta site in the tour.** Include a link to the excellent [meta about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Comment: The tour is that for beginners - to introduce them to the Stack Exchange site they are on. Confusing them with "meta" and "chat" is counter productive. Adding more information about **other** sites detracts from the function of this page.

Comment: I wonder if they were left out because new users can't use those features yet (5 rep needed for Meta, 20 rep needed for chat).  I think you also get "achievement" notifications for those, which probably explain them.

Comment: @jadarnel27: That's a very good point!

Comment: @Oded Would it be possible to incorporate some form of tutorial system that continues to give non-invasive advice to newly registered users until they reach 100 rep? It could even be an opt-out thing. I realize that mentioning meta and chat is not really the purpose of the tour/about but I feel their absence there does affect participation on a lot of new beta. It may not be that critical for chat, but it is especially important for meta.